# Can't install NVIDIA CUDA toolkit

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, cuda

I have an older desktop running a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 260 graphics card. I am currently using Ubuntu 16.04 as my OS. I am running NVIDIA driver version: 340.104. My end goal is to install NVIDIA DIGITS, but in order to do that I need CUDA toolkit. I attempted to install CUDA toolkit 9.0, but after installation and rebooting, I cannot login. Is CUDA toolkit 9.0 usable with my current graphics card and NVIDIA driver? Do I need to install an older version of toolkit instead?

Relevant info:
Processor - AMD FX(tm)-6300 Six-Core Processor.
GPU - GeForce GTX 260.
NVIDIA Driver - 340.104.
OS - Ubuntu 16.04.
Docker - 17.09.0-ce.
NVIDIA Docker - 2.0.0.

Comment: No, CUDA requires a specific driver version and your old card needs the legacy driver and doesn't work with newer versions. It's a catch22.

Comment: Could I still install an older version of CUDA (say version 7.0) and still run DIGITS?